# Converting decimal to hex and vise versa NO FUNCTIONS

Tags: python, hex

I need some help converting decimal to hex with NO functions on python.

I'm having trouble figuring out the algorithm, help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Please tag homework questions as such so that people know how to answer.

Comment: How would you do with pencil and paper?

Comment: sorry its on python and is then sent to teacher

Comment: @codeX think about Matteo's remark, there's more truth in it that you seem to think - first figure out how to solve the problem, THEN transform it into code.

Comment: dont worry i got it working coding forums helped me out

Comment: @codeX and do you actually understand what you just copypasted?  If not you just did yourself a big disservice...

Comment: Congratulations. Now you have learned exactly nothing. Good luck on your upcoming test (and your upcoming job, if any).

Comment: i didnt copy paste they helped me with the algorithm then i was able to list it up

Comment: @codeX but do you understand the algorithm? Do you understand where it came from? At least half the point in homework like this is in coming up with the algorithm to start with - the algorithm, as you've probably noticed, is the hard bit. Finding an algorithm ready-made for you online and converting it into Python is as much a disservice to yourself as copypasting code would be.

Comment: i said helped me with the algorithm not gave it to me. But yer you are right they gave me around 60% of the algorithm and the rest i had to figure out. And yes i do understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo works from right to left.

1. Divide number by 16.  Keep the quotient for next iteration, the remainder is the figure you are looking for.  It will ovbviously be between 0 and 15, convert that to 0..F
2. As long as quotient is >= 16, repeat.

Comment: There's no point in doing someone else's homeworks.

Comment: @thg435 he indicated he had trouble formulating an algo, that's why I laid out the basics of the algorithm, in the hope that he would focus on understanding why it worked, and then convert that knowledge into code.  Seeing the comments I obviously failed...

Comment: Downvote wasn't me and seems to be gone now, but the downvoter probably saw this as handing the OP a direct answer to a homework question. It's tenuous, since you haven't given code without explanation like some answers around here tend to do, but its better to help someone arrive at the solution than giving it (or part of it) to them.

Comment: sorry fvu didn't see your comment if i saw it i would've got it working cause what they sent was basically the same thing. i appreciate your help and time

Comment: @codeX If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. It'll mark this problem as solved, and reward both of of you with some rep points. It'll also help with your reputation score so you should do this whenever an answer solves your problem.

Comment: aha thank you didn't know how to do that he did post a similar algorithm so i will. Dn why ppl said i copied/pasted i asked for help with the algorithm not the code lol.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comments to the question - the easiest way to figure out an algorithm is to forget about the programming language you're working with. If you had a math question saying:

> Write down the hexadecimal for each of the following:
>
> 20 8 16 100

What would you do? Think about the steps you would take. Write yourself out a series of instructions - something a person can follow. There's your algorithm. Once you have that, *then*, and not before, translate it into Python.